# Editible Div not linebreaking

Tags: javascript, css

My div isnt reacting as it supposed to (editible).
It caries on with the text while typing:

[image: text overflows inside div]

I need to make it so it would automaticly go to a new line, I dont know if its css part or JS parts, I tryed everything I could find for css part on internet.
Hare is my css of the div:

```
height: 600px;
width: 1100px;
clear: left;
line-height: 14pt;
float:left;
overflow:hidden;
```

Comment: Please post your markup and better still, a full working snippet.

Comment: This is the default behaviour, and does not wrap: https://jsfiddle.net/yjkasu17/ We need more info.

Comment: Ugh I am sorry to bother you guys, almost gaved up but then I realised I am making a mistake, I wrote <pre> instead divs when I did research, since this script is still there from whenever contenteditible wasnt out yet or wasnt really floating, so there was a js script for it to compelte the task. Thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `word-wrap:break-word;` with `display:inline-block;`:

```css
    #mydiv{
        display:inline-block;
        word-wrap:break-word;
        height: 600px;
        width: 300px;
        clear: left;
        line-height: 14pt;
        float:left;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
```

```html
<div id='mydiv'>   
Please,couldyoustopthenoiseI'mtryingtogetsomerestFromallthunbornchickenvoicesinmyheadWhenIamking,youwillbefirstagainstthewall
</div>
```